# How to change defualt package name when creating new project in android studio

Tags: android-studio

when I create new project I get default package I change it the next time I got the same default package name I want to set my default package name

[image]

Comment: Your answer is here click the link please
---------- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/9599873

Answer (score 0):

Change your application name and after that your package name will change automatically. You also can pick the package name you like.

Comment: I want to change default package name when creating new project the one before 
XX.applicationname